# How to access media library?

Tags: media-library

I'm working on a plugin which uses custom post types.
When creating or editing one of these custom post types in the WP admin backend, one must be able to select or upload a custom background image from the WordPress media gallery/library (for that post particular). So I want to be able to bring up the default WordPress media library in the backend.

Is there a function / hook / api available to call the WordPress media gallery admin window?

I Googled the entire afternoon, but I don't seem to get the results I need.

P.s. I know that I can use the featured image for that purpose, but I want to preserve the featured image for the user.

Comment: First tutorial I found - [WPTuts](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-integrate-the-wordpress-media-uploader-in-theme-and-plugin-options--wp-26052)

Comment: This has been answered here numerous times, please click your tag or search the site.

Comment: I searched the site once again and checked the first 10 result pages of the tag. Either I'm not looking correct or my question is not clear, but I still can't find what I need. Only lateral related questions.

Comment: That WPTuts link is outdated and unnecessarily complicated. [This short tutorial](http://mikejolley.com/2012/12/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/) is what you want.